# Долгий процесс Java EE

Tags: java, java-ee, процесс

Есть сайт. Есть процесс который может занять долгое время. Если такая возможность в Java EE при которой я поставлю процесс на выполнение и если я через время зайду на сайт я буду видеть процесс выполнения операции?

Comment: а какой сервер вы используете?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman TomCat 8

Comment: вы используете spring? или у вас все на чистых servlet и jsp?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman пока что чистый. Если есть в Spring-е такая штука то буду его использовать.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman подскажете?

Comment: Что именно подсказать-то?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman как такое сделать?

Comment: я бы это делал на spring или даже на другом языке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Общая идея это создать polling на клиентской стороне т.е. в браузере.

Клиент (браузер) делает запрос на сервер на создание новой задачи. Сервер создает задачу (как вариант FutureTask) **записывает ее в локальное хранилище (например HashMap)** и возвращает id. Браузер, зная id таски может опрашивать сервер проверяя состояние задачи. Если браузер будет перезагружен (и следовательно потеряет id запущенных задач), то он должен сделать запрос на сервер и получить все существующие запущенные задачи. Последнее уже на усмотрение автора ибо связь пользователь-задача может хранится в Базе Данных или в памяти системы.

Здесь для упрощения кода будет псевдокод, с использованием фреймворка Spring.

Слой REST endpoints. Здесь будет осуществлена обработка входящих запросов. Я предлагаю три запроса на создание long task, получения списка активных задач и получения результатов этих задач.

```
public class Rest {

    private TaskService service;

    @RequestMapping(url = "/task", method = GET)
    public List<Long> getRunningTasks() {
        return service.getRunningTasks();
    }

    @RequestMapping(url = "/task", method = POST)
    public Long submitNewTask(TaskData data) {
        return service.submitTask(data);
    }

    @RequestMapping(url = "/task/:id", method = GET)
    public TaskData submitNewTask(@RequestParameter Long taskId) {
        return service.getTaskData(processId);
    }

}
```

Теперь перейдем к самому хранилищу ваших задач

```
public class LongRunningPool {

    private volatile ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Future> taskPoolStorage = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Future>();

    /**
     * Создаем новую таску
     * @param data - какая-то информация для создания задачи
     * @return - ИД новосозданной задачи
     */
    public Long submitTask(TaskData data) {
        FutureTask task = new MyLongRunningTask(data);

        Long taskId = taskIdGenerator(data);
        //database.saveTaskId(taskId, task); - есди надо, то моэно сохранить в БД задачи

        taskPoolStorage.put(taskId, task);

        return taskId;
    }

    /**
     * сюда можно добавить userId или какой-нибудь идентификатор залогиненого юзера
     * в данном примере будем возвращать вообще все задачи
     * @return список всех задач в массиве
     */
    public List<Long> getRunningTasks() {
        //database.getUserRunningTasks(userId); - если надо, то можно достать из БД

        return taskPoolStorage.keys();
    }

    public TaskData getTaskData(Long taskId) {

        FutureTask task = taskPoolStorage.get(taskId);

        if (task.notComplited()) { //Здесь для упрощения я намеренно опустил точную проверку.
            //в данном месте можно сделать проверну на "завершенность".
            return "Task not complited";
        }

        return task.get();
    }
}
```

Здесь опущена работа с Future и показана идея, которой я советую придерживаться в данной задаче.

**Важно!**

1. Обьект LongRunningPool должен быть один на все приложение. Соответственно если это Spring bean, то он по умолчанию Singleton. Если это без спринга, то должен быть использован шаблон [Singleton (одиночка)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))
2. Методы внутри LongRunningPool должны быть также синхронизированы ибо могут случится непредсказуемые вещи, при одновременном доступе нескольих пользователей
3. Надо сделать очистку HashMap от завершенных задач. Из-за того, что существуют ссылки из HasMap то сборщик мусора не может очистить память и со временем JVM упадет по памяти. По завершении задачи вызывать удаление из HashMap. Также неплохо будет сделать таймер (с гораздо большим временем чем время выполнения задачи), который будет пробегаться по всем задачам и проверять не зависли они. Если зависли, то удалять (опять же все ради памяти).

Comment: а, простите, long polling то где?

Comment: Вы правы - тут обычный polling. Исправлю свой ответ

Answer (score 0):

В *Java EE* есть возможность запускать асинхронные задачи, выглядит это примерно так:

```
@Asynchronous
public Future<String> slowMethod(Order order) throws Exception {
    // slow computation
    return null;
}
```

Подробнее можно посмотреть в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html)

Comment: И тобиш если я запущу такой процесс и через время зайду на сайт я получу данные с этого процесса?

Comment: Этот метод будет выполнен в асинхронном режиме. Если вы сохраните результат выполнения в какое нибудь место и отобразите его потом пользователю,  то да.

Comment: Очевидно, чтобы пользоваться плюшками java ee, вам нужен соответствующий томкат http://openejb.apache.org/tomcat-java-ee.html

Comment: А если я просто обновлю страницу. Как мне в таком случае получить данные? Если процесс ещё не завершился.

Comment: Самой простой вариант (но не самый хороший), сетить из метода в статическое поле  значения. По хорошему же, это должно быть реализовано через Stateful бины c нужным скоупом.

Comment: В сессию тоже не вариант.

Comment: Пример можно, пожалуйста?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbod.html

Comment: А почему вы не рассматриваете реализацию через использование механизма сессии?

Comment: stateful бины с нужным скоупом, т.е. со скоупом session -  вы про это?